# How can I loop through the array of objects and display on dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I'd appreciate any help I can get. I'm currently working on a project and trying to loop over the select dropdown to display the lenses I have on my array but am encountering errors and i'm stuck.

The page loads fine with the HTML content but the select option which displays lenses so users can choose from has been my issue. The dropdown is from an array of camera lenses like this:-

```
lenses: Array(2)
 0: "35mm 1.4"
 1: "50mm 1.6"
```

Here's the Javascript code and the innerHTML:-

```
const urlParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let productId = urlParam.get("id");
let product = null;

  // FETCH API

fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/cameras/" + productId)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })

.then((data) => {
    let lenses = "";

    for (const cameraSelect of data.lenses) {
        lenses += `<option>${lenses}</option> `; //select camera lenses
    }


    //HTML container
      let innerHTML = `
      <div class='col'>
          <div class="card">
          <img src=${data.imageUrl} class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body"></div>
              <h3 class="card-title" >${data.name}</h3>
              <p class="card-text">${data.price}€</p>
              <select id="lenses">
                 <option>${data.lenses}</option>
              </select>
              <h2>result</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
          `;

      document.getElementById("productList").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',innerHTML) ;

      console.log(data);
     
})

.catch(function () {
  window.alert('oops something went wrong! Try again.');
});
```

I'd appreciate any help i can get, thanks

Comment: "_but am encountering errors_" What errors exactly?

Comment: I think it's just a typo. You have ```lenses += `<option>${lenses}</option> `; //select camera lenses``` but I think you mean ```lenses += `<option>${cameraSelect}</option> `; //select camera lenses``` (that is, you have `lenses` [the string you're building] in the option but you probably want `cameraSelect` [the element you're visiting in that loop iteration]).

Comment: @3limin4t0r you confused him a bit.. he changed the other one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use the `cameraSelect` when you are building the `lenses` string.

Then you need to put that populated `lenses` variable in the `innerHTML` variable, for the select options.

```js
const urlParam = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let productId = urlParam.get("id");
let product = null;

// FETCH API

fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/cameras/" + productId)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    let lenses = "";

    for (const cameraSelect of data.lenses) {
      lenses += `<option>${cameraSelect}</option> `; //select camera lenses
    }

    //HTML container
    let innerHTML = `
          <div class='col'>
              <div class="card">
              <img src=${data.imageUrl} class="card-img-top">
              <div class="card-body"></div>
                  <h3 class="card-title" >${data.name}</h3>
                  <p class="card-text">${data.price}€</p>
                  <select id="lenses">
                     ${lenses}
                  </select>
                  <h2>result</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
              `;

    document.getElementById("productList").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', innerHTML);

    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function() {
    window.alert('oops something went wrong! Try again.');
  });
```